# Is it possible to directly assign the return value of a method to a variable?

Tags: java, methods

In JavaScript, it's possible to do something along these lines:

```js
var qwerty = (function() {
    //some code
    return returnValue;
}
```

This would assign *returnValue* to *qwerty*. Is there any way to do something similar in Java? Something like:

```java
int num = {
    public int method() {
        //some code
        return val;
    }
}
```

I understand that I could write out a separate method, but I'd like to do it in a way similar to above as it looks neater and cleaner in the code I'm writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `function` doesn't specify any parameters, you're most-likely looking for the `IntSupplier` functional interface:

```
IntSupplier supplier = () -> {
    int val = ...;
    //some code
    return val;
};

int num = supplier.getAsInt();
```

---

If you **really** want to inline it, then you can use the following (which is unreadable, so I wouldn't recommend it):

```
int num = ((IntSupplier) () -> {
    int val = ...;
    //some code
    return val;
}).getAsInt();
```

Because the above `IntSupplier` isn't stored in a variable, it's logically equivalent to the following:

```
int val = ...;
//some code
int num = val;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Would I have to create a custom functional interface if I were to get outside the realm of prepackaged Java classes?

Comment: You're welcome! And I doubt it. `IntSupplier` is just a specialized form of the more-general `Supplier` functional interface (whose generic type can be anything).

Comment: I see that the `Supplier` ones take no parameters, but are there any other similar interfaces that do? For example, if I had an array I needed to deal with.

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch :) I recommend reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: There are many predefined functional interfaces in [the `java.util.function` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). The ones you can start looking at are `Function` and `BiFunction`.